# Disable RC4 cipher for Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, openssl

I'm currently running Apache 2.2 on a Centos 6.7 machine. I need to disable the usage of the RC4 cipher under openSSL. Here is my current SSL config:

```
SSL Protocol support:
# List the enable protocol levels with which clients will be able to
# connect.  Disable SSLv2 access by default:
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
# List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
# See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
```

I've found various sites recommending changing a bunch of the ciphers permitted at once, but I'm not sure if that would possibly break other things.

Comment: Since you explicitly enabled it, removing it would be a good start.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow a better approach when configuring TLS.

Follow the *Recommended configurations* from Mozilla, a secure TLS configuration is more than disable RC4.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS

But since you are asking for disable RC4 based on your config here is:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
```

Comment: Thanks, the link to the Mozilla site was very informative.

Comment: Yes @JorSol this is correct answer.

Comment: I disagree that the mozilla link is helpful because a) it refers to NGinx and not Apache and b) because it assumes a high degree of expertise. The OP has a very specific question and a specific answer is entirely possible.

Comment: It's ok if you disagree, because a) you have not read the link since it's not Nginx specific, it's about the recommended cipher suites. and b) Set a good security requires some degree of expertise, and the config generator (provided in the link) makes it easy to configure proper cipher suites.

Answer (score 4):

Individual ciphers can be disabled via `SSLCipherSuite` configuration option by adding an exclamation mark (!) in front of them.

So `SSLCipherSuite ALL:!RC4` will enable every openssl cipher except for RC4.
In production, you should use something more robust, for example:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EDH+aRSA+SHA256:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH
```

This will disable `SSLv3`,`TLSv1.0`,`TLSv1.1` so your server will only be accessible via `TLSv1.2`.

Comment: I think this answer is a step in the right direction, but it would be improved to explain the tradeoffs involved by such a change. It could also be expanded to answer additional questions about turning off not just RC4 but SSL and making sure that one supports TLS and AES.

Comment: @S.Imp Updated cipher set to match `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1` config option, present in the question...